# Not able to import numpy in cygwin

Tags: python, numpy, cygwin

I have installed numpy using the cygwin setup, and it is showing as successfully installed. But I am not able to import it in my program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pythonpath.py", line 1, in <module>
import numpy
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from .polynomial import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
from .linalg import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: No such file or directory
```

I checked and found that both `lapack_lite.dll` and `_umath_linalg.dll` are available under `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg`

When I try to reinstall numpy, I get the following message:

```
$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

The package is also up-to-date.

```
 $ pip install numpy --upgrade
 Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

How do I import numpy in my programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply restarted my system and the error went away!

Comment: This saved me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 2):

Set the `$PATH` to:

```bash
 $ PATH=/usr/lib/lapack:$PATH
```

Tested on Python **3.6** and **3.8** on Cygwin.

**Notes:**

1. This solution is the same as given in [Cygwin: import numpy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477318/cygwin-import-numpy-error) in 2018 for Python **2.7** in Cygwin.
2. The OP in that post had a different error message: the second-last line of the traceback read `from . import multiarray`, instead of `from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg`.
3. speedolli's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65783037/) failed for me, with a subsequent error `__all__ += type_check.__all__ // NameError: name 'type_check' is not defined` (and copying files is a bad idea anyway).
4. Restarting (this OP's own accepted solution) did not help me, nor did various re-installs, etc.

**Update:**

It might be more prudenct to put the new directory at the *end* of `$PATH`:

```bash
 $ PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/lapack
```

There are *two* versions of `blas` on my system:

```bash
$ /bin/ls -la /usr/lib/lapack/
total 7612
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Joe None       0 Jan  8 12:02 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Joe None       0 Jan  8 14:52 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Joe None  461331 Nov 29 17:27 cygblas-0.dll
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Joe None 7308307 Nov 29 17:28 cyglapack-0.dll
$ /bin/ls -la /usr/bin/cygblas*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Joe None 21716499 Dec 21 23:19 /usr/bin/cygblas-0.dll
```

The post https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2020-July/009613.html seems to suggest (but I am not an expert) that we should use the `/usr/bin` one:

> libopenblas consist of a single file
> /usr/bin/cygblas-0.dll
> that will precede in PATH the liblapack0
> /usr/lib/lapack/cygblas-0.dll
> and used instead. Removing libopenblas will restore the
> usage of Netlib BLAS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation for Python 3.8 right now. Unfortunately a restart didn't help. But I found the solution:

```
# cygcheck /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-38-x86_64-cygwin.dll
```

--> cygcheck: track_down: could not find cyglapack-0.dll

Solution:

```
# cp /usr/lib/lapack/cyglapack-0.dll /bin
```

After that cyglapack-0.dll is found in /bin, because it is in PATH.