# Cygwin: import numpy error

Tags: python, numpy, cygwin

I am trying to `import numpy` in Cygwin. I get the following error message.

I have `numpy 1.11.2-1`, a.k.a. the `python2-numpy: Python scientific computing module` package, installed through the Cygwin installer. I also have `Python 2.7.14-1`, a.k.a. the `python2: Python 2 language interpreter` package also installed through Cygwin. I don't have a local installation of Python on my machine.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Oct 31 2017, 21:12:13)
[GCC 6.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: No such file or directory
```

`cygcheck`:

```
$ cygcheck -c python2-numpy
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
python2-numpy        1.11.2-1       OK
```

Also, I was able to `import numpy` in `Cygwin` on another computer.

There seem to be a number of posts on this but all lacking a solution that works for me. I tried restarting my computer per [Not able to import numpy in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320132/not-able-to-import-numpy-in-cygwin), but that did not work.

I have also edited my `$PATH` variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:/usr/bin
```

The solution:

```
$ PATH=/usr/lib/lapack:$PATH
```

Comment: what is the output of `cygcheck -c python2-numpy` ?

Comment: Not an answer, but as a workaround: anaconda makes installing numpy really easy. I've spent quite some time in the past trying to get numpy to work (failed building wheel, custom wheels for windows) and anaconda was the most painless solution for me. Could be worth trying

Comment: @matzeri added to original post

Comment: @lucidbrot ha, i remember those same issues. yes, i use anaconda elsewhere but not sure if it will resolve these Cygwin-specific issues. I think it is a $PATH issue. The necessary files exist but Cygwin can't seem to find them. Might be that I am using the wrong formatting of my paths (i.e. should be backslash instead of forward slash? semicolon between paths?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy is unable to load the BLAS library, probably as the PATH was redefined to NOT include `/usr/lib/lapack` or you are not using bash or csh.

```
$ cygcheck -l liblapack0
/etc/profile.d/lapack0.csh
/etc/profile.d/lapack0.sh
/usr/lib/lapack/cygblas-0.dll
/usr/lib/lapack/cyglapack-0.dll
```

For avoiding collision the NETLIB BLAS shared library is under `/usr/lib/lapack`
and the scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` add that directory to the PATH

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/lapack0.sh
LA_PREFIX=/usr
LA_LIBDIR=${LA_PREFIX}/lib
LA_BINDIR=${LA_LIBDIR}/lapack

# Check if the PATH variable is empty or not


if test -n "${PATH}"; then
  # PATH is not empty

  # Check if path is already in PATH
  if ! /bin/echo ${PATH} | /bin/grep -q "${LA_BINDIR}" ; then
    # Path is not already in PATH, append it to PATH
    export PATH="${PATH}:${LA_BINDIR}"
  fi
else
  # PATH is empty
  export PATH="${LA_BINDIR}"
fi

unset LA_PREFIX
unset LA_LIBDIR
unset LA_BINDIR
```

Comment: My path includes `/usr/lib/`. Doesn't that mean BLAS is also visible since it is a subdirectory? Also, I did `echo $PATH` then `/etc/profile.d/lapack0.sh` then `echo $PATH`. The `$PATH$` is the same even after running the shell script.

Comment: Interesting. I did: `$ PATH=/usr/lib/lapack:$PATH` then `$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lapack:/usr/bin` then `python` then `import numpy` succeeded. How did you figure out the error was BLAS? I'm curious so I can resolve future issues with similar steps.

Comment: blas and lapack are the only main shared lib with that special settings. I tried removing both from PATH and cygblas-0.dll produced the same error message than yours. The PATH directories are not expanded in sub ones

Answer (score 0):

For me, to run Cygwin Python from Windows (exotic use case, I know), I had to add c:\cygwin64\lib\lapack to the PATH.